# A error when I use clang to compile c file?

Tags: c, clang, clang++, stdio

When I used clang to compile c file, an error occurred.
The c file is easy.
main.c

```
#include <STDIO.H>

int main() {
    printf("Hello\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I used the following command in windows.

> clang main.c

error

```
C:\Users\bo\Desktop>clang main.c
In file included from main.c:1:
F:\Microsoft Visual Studio\VC98\Include\STDIO.H:70:22: error: typedef
  redefinition with different types ('unsigned int' vs 'unsigned long long')

typedef unsigned int size_t;
                 ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: I am not aware of a standard header `STDIO.H` - probably you want `stdio.h` ? Bzw: The error message clang reported would be great...

Comment: You're using *clang* compiler which apparently includes a file from *VStudio*. That doesn't seem right. Maybe reset the *%INCLUDE%*  env var before invoking *clang*? or explicitly pass the paths to its include files. Also you might want to use lower case (*stdio.h*), not a problem on *Win*, but still. Also the *size\_t* definition mismatch seems related to 32/64 bit.

Comment: VC98 was Visual Studio version 6, released in 1998.  Of course its .h files are grossly unsuitable to be used with clang.  Clang is directly supported by VS2017, the community edition is a free download.

Comment: What does `echo %C_INCLUDE_PATH%` (in the same console where you execute *clang*) output? Hmm, I tried running *clang 5.0.3* (from *Android Studio*) with include paths from either *VStudio 2015* or *VStudio 2017* but got weird errors.

Comment: `F:\Microsoft Visual Studio\VC98\Include\STDIO.H` sounds like a very old outdated stdio.h file.

Comment: It seems that the windows SDK you have on your system is too old for LLVM version. Possibly you're compiling for 64 bits with a 32 bits SDK. Try with command line `clang -m32 main.c`. Anyway update your system downloading last win SDK.

Comment: I reset the %INCLUDE% env var before invoking clang. It works. VC98 is too old.

Answer (score 0):

> English is not my native language, maybe I'll have some problems in
>   expression, I'll try to express clearly to help you.

I see you wanna use clang compiler on Windows, the warning in command-line explains that your version of Visual Studio Library is too old for LLVM version, I don't think VisualC++6.0 is the IDE you're using now, maybe you just installed it and put it away. Probably this error was caused by VC6.0.

So I suggest that check your environment variables, probably there is a "include" variable that file directory is "F:\Microsoft Visual Studio\VC98\Include\" like in that warning. Just delete, and if there are more variables contain VC6.0 such as "Path", delete it which contain VC6.0 if it's not necessary for you.

Try to use VS2019 instead of VC6.0, it can provides the newest Windows SDK for Clang.

Comment: If still doesn't work try to uninstall VC6.0, and delete all the environment variables I mentioned above.